# LED before input to Micocontroller

Tags: microcontroller, led

I am designing a circuit to provide a logic high (5V) or logic low (0V) to a microcontroller. How can I incorporate an LED into the circuit so that it is on/off when the logic is high/low, while still providing the microcontroller with either 5V or 0V.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Think of it as your digital signal driving two things, the microcontroller and the LED.  If this is just for indicator use on your bench, then 5 mA thru any normal LED will be bright enough.  If whatever is driving the digital line can source 5 mA then you hook that line to the micro normally, but add a resistor and LED in series to ground.  Let's say the LED drops 2 V at 5 mA, which means the resistor would need to drop 3 V at 5 mA.  3V / 5mA = 600Ω

If the digital output can't handle 5 mA, then have it turn on a transistor which turns on the LED.  Here is a nice simple circuit that requires the minimum possible current from the digital signal to light the LED given the gain of the transistor:

[image]

Comment: I was testing this out, but adding a resistor and LED in series to ground seems to make the voltage drop from 5V to a value lower (usually around 3V). Is this because I'm not selecting the right resistor?

Comment: @AmandeepGrewal, if you're referring to the voltage going into the base of the BJT in Olin's answer, it means that the source can't drive the transistor directly due to too high impedance. You will have to either increase the drive capability of the original voltage source with a buffer or increase the input impedance of the LED driver by using an opamp or FET.

Comment: @tyblu, I meant if I was just to "you hook that line to the micro normally, but add a resistor and LED in series to ground" as Olin said.

Comment: @AmandeepGrewal Same thing holds though... If your voltage is dropping then your source isn't able to supply the current and you need to add a fet, bjt, or some other type of buffer/switch.

Comment: @AmandeepGrewal - your query re loading is completely covered by Olin's answer. What you tried is covered by his first pagaragraph. He said that if that did not work then you should try the solution in the second paragraph. As you report that the solution in the first paragraph did not work then you should, as it says, now try the solution in his second paragraph.